# filter and regex issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to filter an array with a function.

```
if (this.pendingItems.customer?.emailAddresses) {
  this.pendingItems.customer.emailAddresses.filter(email => {
    isEmailValid(email);
  });
}
```

the function isEmailValid()

```
export function isEmailValid(s: string): boolean {
  const re =
    /^[a-z0-9+-][a-z0-9_+-]*(\.[a-z0-9_+-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+\.)+[a-z0-9-]{2,}$/i;
  return re.test(s);
}
```

return the correct response (true or false) with the emails(test@email.com and test2email) I pass it, but the filter don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was:

```
if (this.pendingItems.customer?.emailAddresses) {
  this.pendingItems.customer.emailAddresses = this.pendingItems.customer.emailAddresses.filter(isEmailValid);
}
```

I forgot to reassign the variable ;p

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your expression slightly. The method you pass to the filter function should return true/false but it always returns void (which will be cast to false).

```
filter(email => isEmailValid(email))
or
filter(isEmailValid)
or
filter(email => { return isEmailValid(email) })
```

In case you missed it - you forgot to return the result of the isEmailValid ;)

Comment: I have already tested that.
For an exemple if I trie this:
```if (this.pendingItems.customer?.emailAddresses) {
      this.pendingItems.customer.emailAddresses.filter(isEmailValid);
      console.log(this.pendingItems.customer.emailAddresses);
    }```
the log return the 2 emails: test@email.com and test2email
I realy don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Check your regex in a regex tester like https://regex101.com/

Comment: Also calling `.filter` does not change the list - it returns a new list - you can reassign it you want to overwrite the first list `const newlist = oldlist.filter(someExpression)`